# $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue on a site I'm building where the datatable is not
loading (on server) but works fine on local host (xamp). Firefox throws an error, "$ is not defined."

I've googled the errors, and I found a friend's solution that jquery.js file has not been included or your reference to it is pointing to the wrong location.

But I checked the file path twice & thrice and it is correct & the jquery.js is also there.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Maybe you are using some other js framework like prototypejs which conflicts with the `$` function.

Comment: and firebug shows you that jquery.js was loaded successfully, or are you just sure that the given path to the file should be correct?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: If `$` was defined by a different framework, he wouldn't get such an error.

Comment: As it is on a live server could you give us the URL?

Comment: Thanks friends, the problem was that due to slow browsing speed jquery.js failed to browsed as early as the script executed ... Thanks a lot to all

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the `$` object is used *before* jquery.js is imported.

A typical cause of this would be using some kind of jQuery plugin:

If you have this:

```
<script src="jquery.someplugin.js">
<script src="jquery.js">
```

try changing it to this:

```
<script src="jquery.js">
<script src="jquery.someplugin.js">
```

**To be sure:** Use Firefox with Firebug plugin and look where exactly the problem occured. Then you can be sure.

Answer (score 5):

If jQuery is correctly included in your page, maybe another library (such as prototype) is also present. Thus, to avoid conflict, jQuery provides another a [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function. In this case, the `$` is replaced by `jQuery`.

So instead of doing something like `$("some selector").doSomething();` you will have to do `jQuery("some selector").doSomething();`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like juery.js is not readable. Have you tried accessing jquery.js directly from your browser? If you get a access denied error, chmod the file to 644 (rw-r--r--).

Comment: In firefox if you view source then your src to jQuery.js will be clickable, and will quickly show if you are 404ing.  This way is better than typing into your address bar, as you might accidentally change the path.