# passing the value from a textbox to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html textbox and get the value from it with the following code:

```
$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", function(){
var value = $("#textbox1").val();
});
```

I then attempted to pass that value to a different function

```
function loadPdf(pdfPath) {
    var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument(pdfPath);
    return pdf.then(renderPdf);
}

loadPdf(value);
```

But the value isn't being passed. I then attempted to do the following:

```
$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", 
    function(){
      var value = $("#textbox1").val();
      alert('The Value in Textbox is '+value);
});
```

to see if the value was displayed, but that didn't work either (didn't get any output)

EDIT: I do get an error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And if I remove the $ it says `('#getTextBoxValue).on is not a function`

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use jQuery before jQuery is loaded. The least you can do is **read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)**. Or don't use jQuery. *"if I remove the $ it says ('#getTextBoxValue).on is not a function"* Of course, since strings (`'#getTextBoxValue'`) don't have a method `.on`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076999/is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

$ is a reference to jQuery.  This works for me if jQuery is included:

```
<input id="textbox1"></input>
<button id="getTextBoxValue">Get value</button>

$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", 
    function(){
        var value = $("#textbox1").val();
        alert('The Value in Textbox is '+value);
     });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3qhw10dw/)

If you wanted to do it without jQuery, use `document.getElementById("textbox1").value;` and add the onclick either inline or via normal javascript also:

```
document.getElementById("getTextBoxValue").onclick = function(){
    var value = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    alert('The Value in Textbox is '+value);
};
```

After you get that to work, just replace the alert with loadPdf(value);
the `var value` is local to the onclick function, so has to be accessed inside of that function or made global.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have jQuery loaded on the page, it should be as easy as calling your helper function inside the click event.

```
$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", function(){
 loadPdf( $("#textbox1").val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is due to scope.

You are defining your variables within the function with var.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var value;
  var pdf;
  var value;

  /* Then do your functions. This will make then global. 
  When you type then within your functions do not put var in front of them */
});
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but "due to scope" is a vague explanation for the problem. Felix Kling's comment explains the problem better: he is trying to use jQuery before jQuery is loaded. Please, review your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this as javascript but The code you are using to grab your values and bind your functions is jQuery.  The error you are getting is telling you that there is no mapping of "$" to jQuery.  If you want to make sure you have the reference set, you can replace the $ with the string "jQuery" so `$('someselector')` becomes `jQuery('someselector')`.

BUT, this may just be the console you are using.  You have another error which is probably the issue.  You have this:

```
$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", function(){
    var value = $("#textbox1").val();
});
```

In this your value is locally scoped in the callback.  Unless you do something with it before the function exits, you lose it completely.  If you intend to do something with it later, you have to globally scope it by bringing it out of any function definition.

```
var value;
...
function someFunction(){
    ...
    $('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", function(){
        value = $("#textbox1").val();
    });
}
```